# Problem understanding how express session saves client in memory

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I am currently building a rest api with express backed up with a mongo database. At the moment, I have setup a simple authentication process which saves a session object in the mongo database.Thing is I don't send back anything to the client such as a session ID. Still, when i close the browser and open it again, then log req.session, i still get the user id that i previously saved in the session. I was wondering how does express know that it is the same client. If someone could clearify this to me, it would be great.

Here is how i set the session:

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "This is a secret",
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 // 1 week
    },
    store: store,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  })
);
```

Comment: can you share the code on how you initalize the session? I would expect that the default cookie behaviour is enabled (and thus the cookie is sent back to your browser)

Comment: Yes you are right (I edited the question), the cookie is enabled. Does that mean that this cookie is automatically saved in browser?

Comment: yes, this is standard behaviour from browser when they receive cookie headers